# Gspread, cant make a cell blank

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-3.4, gspread

When using gspread with python3 it seems like its not possible to make a cell value blank, is this really the case? Everytime I try updating a cell with value "" the cell then looks blank but formulas arent working. Even when using

```
sheet.clear()
```

it doesnt make the cells blank. Is there any workaround? Its irritating when

```
ISBLANK(cell)
```

doesnt get triggered due to some weird values from gspread. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the same but for excel and linux the code doesnt update to the new spreadsheet every time it is ran. Did you check the google spreadsheet to see if it got emptied? For example when I run a code to see the contents of A1 in excel I find one answer. But if I go and change the contents of A1 and run the same code I still get the same answer I do not know why it happens but it happens in python 2.7 for me idk about python3.4.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes it updated, everything is working great except I cant get cells to turn blank somehow, looking at the import code it seems like empty cell value is None but when trying to update a cell with None value it turns into a string instead

Comment: Yes it does, everytime

Comment: Only thing I can think of doing is to change all the formulas to check cell != "" instead of ISBLANK(cell)

Comment: Um i think this is the same error i got. For me i have to copy my excel sheet and change the name then make the code read the new file not the old one.  Otherwise after the first run of the code it stores information and reuses it so nothing happens.